# Does opening or closing a checking account show up on a credit report or affect credit score?

Tags: united-states, checking-account

Suppose someone in the United States took any of the following actions:

1. Open a new checking account.
2. Closing an existing checking account.
3. Close the checking account with the longest standing.

Would it have an impact on credit score? Would it even show up in a credit report?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

None of what you mentioned is part of your credit report, ***unless*** you close an account that was overdrawn and has been referred by the bank for collections.

In the U.S., your banking history is maintained by several companies, the largest of which is ChexSystems.  When you open a new account, the bank will request your history from one of these firms and, just like with credit reports, if you have adverse banking history (which often includes information about bounced checks) then the bank may not be willing to open the account.

Comment: Given they charge crazy fees for bounced checks surely they'd actively want customers who throw money away in charges?

Comment: There's no assurance the bank would be able to collect those charges, is there?  If the person can't keep enough in the bank to cover the checks they write then it's likely they won't be able to pay the fees either and the account would be closed for insufficient funds and end up in collections.  Banks only note ChexSystems issues with bounced checks if those checks are left unpaid.  So if you write a check that is returned and then make it good, ChexSystems won't care about it.